# How to display all the values in the table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, fetch

I am having trouble with the employment_table i have in the code bellow. I want the table to display ALL jobs that they have inserted into the table. Instead it only displays the latest one. The values that display these are $ee ($start and $end for start and end dates). Once again the problem is it doesnt display all the jobs just the last one. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Isit to do with an array?  Thanks in advance

```
  $employment_table = "no table";
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE userID='$profile_id' AND type='job'";
  $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     $h_id = $row["id"];
     $ee = $row["ee"];
     $htype = $row["type"];
     $unixstart = $row["start"];
     $unixend = $row["end"];
       $start = date("d/m/Y",$unixstart);
       $end =  date("d/m/Y",$unixend);
  $employment_table = "<table>";
  $employment_table .= "<tr>";
  $employment_table .= "<th>Company Name</td>";
  $employment_table .= " <th>Start Date</td>";
  $employment_table .= "<th>End Date</td>";
  $employment_table .= "</tr>";
  $employment_table .= "<tr>";
  $employment_table .= "<td>".$ee."</td>";
  $employment_table .= "<td>".$start."</td>";
  $employment_table .= "<td>".$end."</td>";
  $employment_table .= "</tr>";
  $employment_table .= "</table>";      
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the `$employment_table` variable each time in the loop.  Take the `<table>` and `</table>` tags out of the loop - e.g.

```
    $employment_table = "<table>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
         $h_id = $row["id"];
         $ee = $row["ee"];
         $htype = $row["type"];
         $unixstart = $row["start"];
         $unixend = $row["end"];
           $start = date("d/m/Y",$unixstart);
           $end =  date("d/m/Y",$unixend);

      $employment_table .= "<tr>";
      $employment_table .= "<th>Company Name</td>";
      $employment_table .= " <th>Start Date</td>";
      $employment_table .= "<th>End Date</td>";
      $employment_table .= "</tr>";
      $employment_table .= "<tr>";
      $employment_table .= "<td>".$ee."</td>";
      $employment_table .= "<td>".$start."</td>";
      $employment_table .= "<td>".$end."</td>";
      $employment_table .= "</tr>";

     }
$employment_table .= "</table>";
```

Comment: Ah yes it worked! thanks for the quick response and solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `$employment_table` with every iteration.
Also you create a new table for every row.

So do following:

```
$employment_table = "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $h_id = $row["id"];
    $ee = $row["ee"];
    $htype = $row["type"];
    $unixstart = $row["start"];
    $unixend = $row["end"];
    $start = date("d/m/Y",$unixstart);
    $end =  date("d/m/Y",$unixend);
    $employment_table .= "<tr>";
    $employment_table .= "<th>Company Name</td>";
    $employment_table .= " <th>Start Date</td>";
    $employment_table .= "<th>End Date</td>";
    $employment_table .= "</tr>";
    $employment_table .= "<tr>";
    $employment_table .= "<td>".$ee."</td>";
    $employment_table .= "<td>".$start."</td>";
    $employment_table .= "<td>".$end."</td>";
    $employment_table .= "</tr>";
}
$employment_table .= "</table>";
```